# Externally exposed frontend service (NodePort) can't communicate with internally available backend service (ClusterIP)

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

The app consists of 3 components: frontend, backend and Redis. The frontend communicates only with the backend, the Redis service communicates only with the backend service. All pods run correctly, at least logs don't show anything disturbing.

The backend is built with NodeJS/ExpressJS, the frontend: with React.

Services are configured in the following way:

`frontend:`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: plg-frontend
  labels:
    name: plg-frontend-service
    app: playground-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30010
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: plg-frontend-pod
    app: playground-app
```

`backend:`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: plg-backend
  labels:
    name: plg-backend-service
    app: playground-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4000
    targetPort: 5011
  selector:
    name: plg-backend-pod
    app: playground-app
```

All services run correctly:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
plg-backend       ClusterIP   10.233.23.12   <none>        4000/TCP       2d3h
plg-frontend      NodePort    10.233.63.20   <none>        80:30010/TCP   2d3h
redis             ClusterIP   10.233.59.37   <none>        6379/TCP       2d3h
```

At the moment, the frontend running on host's IP, let's say http://10.11.12.13:30010, tries to call the backend's internal endpoint, so 10.233.23.12:5011 (the backend's `targetPort`). Connection times out. Should I expose the backend service to become `NodePort` to be accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to expose using NodePort unless you intend to let the backend service accessible on the host network. Your frontend should be calling 10.233.23.12:**4000**, not 5011 which is the backing pods listening on.

Comment: Thank you, @gohm'c! I `exec`'ed into the frontend container and tried to send some requests using `curl` to the backend's URL 10.233.23.12:4000 - all of them received replies, so the backend is reachable internally. However, still no success trying to achieve the same behavior in the website - the frontend sends requests that time out eventually. All services and pods were restarted. I run out of ideas how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: `...no success trying to achieve the same behavior in the website - the frontend sends requests...` - the "frontend" here you meant the **react running on client side browser**? If true, you can't do this as they are not on the same network. Unless your pod runs on a node that has a public IP, you can connect via <public IP>:<NodePort #>.